# Warning when using react hooks in HoC

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-hooks

I've created a a higher order component that is supposed to add some additional functionality to my components. However, when I use react hooks in this component, I get the following eslint warning.

> React Hook "React.useEffect" cannot be called inside a callback. React
>   Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React
>   Hook function. (react-hooks/rules-of-hooks)

Why am I getting this warning? Is it considered bad practice to use hooks in a HoC?

Minimal example:

```
const Hello = props => <p>Greetings {props.name}</p>;

const Wrapper = Component => props => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Do something here
  }, []);
  return <Component {...props} />;
};

export default Wrapper(Hello)
```

codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-tree-5kscc

Comment: One of the complexities that hooks solve is the ability to share logic between components through [custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html). refactor your `HOC` into a custom hook

Comment: @AsafAviv Custom hooks don't solve all problems. One of the most powerful things in `HOC` components is the ability to return early and render different component, now try that with hooks.

Comment: @AsafAviv Isn't that what `render props` pattern is for?

Comment: @PrashanD It can be, but now you can just extract the state into a custom hook and use that hook in your components instead of render props

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Convert the

```js
props => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Do something here
  }, []);
  return <Component {...props} />;
};
```

inside your HOC to a function (react-hooks/rules-of-hooks is throwing that warning you showed when used in an arrow function returned by a HOC)

So, change it to

```js
const Wrapper = Component =>
  function Comp(props) {
    React.useEffect(() => {
      console.log("useEffect");
    }, []);
    return <Component {...props} />;
  };
```

and the effect gets triggered.

[Here is a working example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-ishizaka-bsdm2)

Comment: I always use the hooks this way in the functional components returned by a HOC.

Comment: The returned function must not be a anonymous function。So `()=>{}` and `function (){}` is not allowed, and `function myComponent(){}` is Ok.

Comment: Why is `const Wrapper = Component => props => {` incorrect? I have been doing that a lot to convert hooks to HOCs. Have I been doing it wrong this whole time. Is this just for the linting rule?

Answer (score 3):

The [official React Hooks documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level) says:

> Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks.

As @AsafAviv said, you should refactor your HOC into a custom hook to avoid violation the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

---

The reason is [described in the FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-does-react-associate-hook-calls-with-components) by the way:

> #### How does React associate Hook calls with components?
>
> React keeps track of the currently rendering component. Thanks to the Rules of Hooks, we know that Hooks are only called from React components (or custom Hooks — which are also only called from React components).
>
> There is an internal list of “memory cells” associated with each component. They’re just JavaScript objects where we can put some data. When you call a Hook like useState(), it reads the current cell (or initializes it during the first render), and then moves the pointer to the next one. This is how multiple useState() calls each get independent local state.

Comment: I get that the Rules of Hooks make sure that react hooks are only called from inside React components. But this function does indeed return a React component, so I don't see the issue. Isn't the linting rule just too broad?

Comment: Can you also add a solution, in this case?

Comment: It's got to be a bug in the rule.. it's not complaining when the inner function is named, which should not make any difference.

Comment: Apparently, the error is valid. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7033
I just don't agree with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use react hooks in the functional components or in the custom Hooks.
rewrite your HOC:

```
const Hello = props => <p>Greetings {props.name}</p>;

const HookDoSomething = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Do something here
  }, []);
}

const Wrapper = Component => props => {
  HookDoSomething()
  return <Component {...props} />;
};

export default Wrapper(Hello)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the file where you have your HoC defined, simply add the following to the top of the file:

```
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/rules-of-hooks */
```

[Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and [higher-order components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) are two completely different things. Anyone who says a HoC can be replaced by a hook has either never actually written a HoC or playing semantics games.

When I write a HoC, I often have to disable the `rules-of-hooks` eslint rule because the rule is too stringent wrt what it thinks is a hook or component. HoC is more akin to a component than a hook, but the rule does not recognize this.

Comment: yes it's really annoying

Answer (score 0):

`Short Answer`: You just need to change the callback to a PascalCase function or useSomething function. This is because eslint rule has some heuristic that you need to follow in order for it to detect components.

You will need to change your code to

```
const Wrapper = Component => {
  return function WithWrapper(props){
    React.useEffect(() => {
        // Do something here
      }, []);
    return <Component {...props} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the name to lower case
like :

```
withWrrapperHOC = Comp => props => {
 useEffect(()=>{
  //...
 },[])
 return (<Comp {...props}>)
}
```