# pass data to a Layout component gatsbyJS

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I want to pass data to layout Component, the data is from an API, cockpitCMS to be exact and the data is slug to be exact too.

io have tried this

```
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

export const slugs = () => {
  const { data } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query slug{
        allCockpitPost {
            edges {
            node {
                title {
                slug
                }
               }
            }
        }
    }
    `
  )
  return data.allCockpitPost.edges.node.title
}
```

but, I get this instead...  `React Hook "useStaticQuery" is called in function "slugs" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function`

maybe because we can't use usestaticQuery twice, and it is already been used in the SEO component.

Comment: Are these helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60795387/5385381 https://stackoverflow.com/a/56288582/5385381

Comment: no, I think it is a different problem, my problem is passing data or an array, while that post is about style.

Comment: Your problem is `React Hook "useStaticQuery" is called in function "slugs" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function`, right? Both the linked questions mention the same arror.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is the way you use hook. Basically you have some ways to use `useStaticQuery` or any hook in a function:

- That function NEED to return a `React Component`.
- Other wise, that should be a HOC.

Example code for first way:

```
import AnyComponent from '../some-where';
const MockComponent = (props) => {
  const { mockData } = useStaticQuery(anyQuery);

  return (
    <AnyComponent mockData={mockData}>
  )
}
export default MockComponent
```

Example code for second way:

```
const withMockHOC = (AnyOtherComponent) => (props) => {
  const { mockData } = useStaticQuery(anyQuery);

  return <AnyOtherComponent {...props} mockData={mockData} />;
};
```

Hope this help.