# unable to use hooks in a component that is being returned

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am following along with a React.js tutorial.

In it, a website was created with class based components. But now, it's being converted to functional component.

This is a HOC, which was at first returning a class based component but now a functional one.

Now, when i use useState and useEffect in it, it gives the error that  :

```
Line 8:36:  React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function
```

and

```
Line 29:9:  React Hook "useEffect" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be 
called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function
```

i'm using react version 17, while the instructor was using version 16.

This is the code when it was **class based and working:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Modal from "../../components/UI/Modal/Modal";
const WithErrorHandler = (WrappedComponent , axios) =>
{
    return class extends Component
    {
        state = {
            error : null
        }
        componentWillMount()
        {

            this.resInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(res => res , (error) =>
            {
                this.setState({error : error});

            });

            
            this.reqInterceptor =axios.interceptors.request.use((req) =>
            {

                this.setState({error : null});
                
                return(req);
            } );


        }
       
        componentWillUnmount()
        {
            axios.interceptors.request.eject(this.reqInterceptor);
            axios.interceptors.response.eject(this.resInterceptor);

        }

        errorConfirmedHandler = () =>
        {
            this.setState({error : null});
        }

        render()
        {
            return(
                <>
                <Modal 
                show = {this.state.error}
                modalClosed = {this.errorConfirmedHandler}>
                    {this.state.error ? this.state.error.message : null}
                </Modal>
                <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
                </>
            );
        }
    }
    
}

export default  WithErrorHandler;
```

and this is the code when it's converted to **functional component and not working :**

```
import React, {useState , useEffect} from 'react'
import Modal from "../../components/UI/Modal/Modal";
const WithErrorHandler = (WrappedComponent , axios) =>
{

    return props => {
        const [error , seterror] = useState(null);
        
        
            const resInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(res => res , (error) =>
            {
                seterror(error);

            });

            
            const reqInterceptor =axios.interceptors.request.use((req) =>
            {

                seterror(null);
                
                return(req);
            } );


        

        useEffect(() =>
        {
            return () =>
            {
                axios.interceptors.request.eject(reqInterceptor);
                axios.interceptors.response.eject(resInterceptor);
            }

        } , [reqInterceptor , resInterceptor])
        

        const errorConfirmedHandler = () =>
        {
            seterror(null);
        }

        
            return(
                <>
                <Modal 
                show = {error}
                modalClosed = {errorConfirmedHandler}>
                    {error ? error.message : null}
                </Modal>
                <WrappedComponent {...props}/>
                </>
            );
        
    }
    
}

export default  WithErrorHandler;
```

Any help or guidance will be appreciated, thankyou.

Comment: Could you include example code of where you instantiate the HOC?

Comment: This Stackoverflow post can give you insights into your warnings: [Warning when using react hooks in HoC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288448/warning-when-using-react-hooks-in-hoc). On a side note, Hook was created to somewhat replace HOC, so consider ways to make `WithErrorHandler` into a custom hook instead

Answer (score 0):

Do you need those effects to run inside the returned component? One solution is to move all the hooks outside into the Wrapping component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Modal from '../../components/UI/Modal/Modal'

const WithErrorHandler = (WrappedComponent, axios) => {
  const [error, seterror] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const resInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(
      (res) => res,
      (error) => {
        seterror(error)
      },
    )

    const reqInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
      seterror(null)

      return req
    })

    return () => {
      axios.interceptors.request.eject(reqInterceptor)
      axios.interceptors.response.eject(resInterceptor)
    }
  }, [axios.interceptors.request, axios.interceptors.response])

  return (props) => {
    const errorConfirmedHandler = () => {
      seterror(null)
    }

    return (
      <>
        <Modal show={error} modalClosed={errorConfirmedHandler}>
          {error ? error.message : null}
        </Modal>
        <WrappedComponent {...props} />
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default WithErrorHandler
```

Alternatively, you can turn that callback into its own component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Modal from '../../components/UI/Modal/Modal'

const WithErrorHandler = (WrappedComponent, axios) => (props) => (
  <Wrapped {...props} axios={axios} WrappedComponent={WrappedComponent} />
)

const Wrapped = ({ axios, WrappedComponent, ...props }) => {
  const [error, seterror] = useState(null)

  const resInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (res) => res,
    (error) => {
      seterror(error)
    },
  )

  const reqInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
    seterror(null)

    return req
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      axios.interceptors.request.eject(reqInterceptor)
      axios.interceptors.response.eject(resInterceptor)
    }
  }, [axios.interceptors.request, axios.interceptors.response, reqInterceptor, resInterceptor])

  const errorConfirmedHandler = () => {
    seterror(null)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={error} modalClosed={errorConfirmedHandler}>
        {error ? error.message : null}
      </Modal>
      <WrappedComponent {...props} />
    </>
  )
}

export default WithErrorHandler
```

Comment: the second one seems to be working without errors, but in the class based one, if i mess up the firebase url, it shows the popup from this component, but when i used the second one, it just showed a blank page, is it something wrong with my implementation ?